# Meaning of "Propose" in following sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was watching Big bang theory when I came across the conversation-

Person 1: I wanted to apologize and thought to make it up to you.

Person 2: And how do you propose to do that?

Could someone please help.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up ***propose*** in the dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Propose is sometimes use in the sense of a "proposal of marriage", however there is an another meaning:

> put forward (a plan or suggestion) for consideration by others

You will see *propose* in this sense used in French restaurants suggesting a particular dish.

The idea is that Person 1 might have a plan to apologise and make reparation but for this to work Person 2 will need to find this plan acceptable. Person 2's response

> How do you propose to do that

is (depending upon the tone of voice) probably slightly negative or challenging; reminding Person 1 that it should not be assumed that the plan will be acceptable.